# Why is there is some padding before the first line in my TextArea?

Tags: css

There is some padding before the first line in my `<textarea>`.

I set `style="padding:0;"`, but the "padding" is still there. Why is this?

```
<p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65" </textarea></p>
```

css file:

```
.addBlock {
    background-color:#E9F8BE;
    border:2px solid #D6E684;
    float:left;
    dth:94%;
    margin-left:22px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.addQuestionBlock p {
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-left:20px;
    width:650px;
}
.addBlock p.selectQnLabel {
    padding-top:16px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
.addBlock p .input {
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#888 #BBB #BBB #888;
    color:#333;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: If you have a line break between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` then remove it. I mean write `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` in same line in code.

Comment: <p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65" </textarea></p>

Comment: It should be: `<p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65"></textarea></p>` You forgot closing `>` of `<textarea>`

Comment: @user630209: Please make a demonstration of your problem with [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com).

Comment: <p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65" </textarea></p>  css file  .addBlock{ background-color:#E9F8BE;
border:2px solid #D6E684;float:left;dth:94%;
margin-left:22px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}  .addQuestionBlock p
     {padding-top:4px;padding-left:20px;width:650px;} .addBlock p.selectQnLabel
     {padding-top:16px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#333; font-family:Georgia,Times New Roman,Times,serif;} 
   .addBlock p .input{background-color:#F9F9F9;border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#888 #BBB #BBB #888;color:#333;padding-left:0px;}

Comment: ya according to this jsfiddle everything looks ok - http://jsfiddle.net/jonezy/tgv6Z/

Comment: Yep all is fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/NpaNE/ Just seems your mess up with the textarea did it...

Comment: to see it correctly you must wrap the `p` with an element (probably `div`) with class `addBlock`. But in this case, it also looks ok http://jsfiddle.net/tgv6Z/1/

Answer (score 1):

you didnt close your textarea

```
<p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65" </textarea></p>
```

should be

```
<p><textarea id="quest" class="input" rows="4" cols="65"></textarea></p>
```

working example here...
http://cssizer.com/F9356A7D